# How can a method access a property of a caller?

Tags: swift, struct, nested

I have a struct with 2 properties, which are dependant on each other. An instance can be created by passing either of them as an argument, the initializer will then call a function to calculate the respective other one. This calculation needs the value of another variable, which is declared as a global var at the top of my playground:

```
var grid: Int = 8

struct myStruct {
    var valueAsTuple: (Int,Int,Int)
    var valueAsInt: Int

    init(_ value: (Int,Int,Int)) {
        self.valueAsTuple = value
        self.valueAsInt = 0
        self.valueAsInt = getIntFromTuple(value)
    }

    init(singleInt: Int) {
        self.valueAsTuple = (0,0,0)
        self.valueAsInt = singleInt
        self.valueAsTuple = getTupleFromInt(singleInt)
    }

    func getIntFromTuple(tuple: (Int,Int,Int)) -> Int {

        // do some math using the global grid variable

        return result
    }

    func getTupleFromInt(int: Int) -> (Int,Int,Int) {

        // do some math using the global grid variable

        return result
    }
}
```

This works fine in the playground. However, in the end the myStruct will never be used as a single instance, but another struct will hold an array of myStructs. This encapsulating struct will have a property "grid", and this property should be used when calculating the properties of myStruct.

Multiple instances of the encapsulating property could be created, each of them having a different value for "grid", so that an instance of myStruct which is created within one instance of the outer struct will get a different result for the respective other property than one which is created within a different instance.

I am new to object orientated programming, so I am still learning how to organize my code to achieve my specific aim.

I tried to nest the myStruct into the outer struct, but I get the error: "instance member 'grid' cannot be used on type 'myStruct'.

Changing the grid var to static makes the nested struct see it, but that would make it impossible to give each instance of the outer struct a different grid value.

So, in short, what would be a swift way to code objects that must use properties of their surrounding scope?

EDIT:

I try to give a clearer example:

Imagine you have a number of eggs and you want to store them in boxes. An egg can have an absolute number (m), and it can be the (n)th egg in box (o). You can tell the initializer to store an egg at an absolute position (m), or at a specific position of a specific box.

Now there are boxes which can hold 6 eggs and such that hold 10. Of course, I can pass the boxes capacity (the 'grid' value) on each initialization of a new egg, but what I am looking for is a convenient way for letting the initializer know which box size the array I want to append to has:

```
shelfWithSmallBoxes.boxesArray.append(21)
// now there is an egg at absolute position 21
print(shelfWithSmallBoxes.boxesArray.last.asTuple

shelfWithLargeBoxes.boxesArray.append(21)
// also here is an egg at absolute position 21
print(shelfWithLargeBoxes.boxesArray.last.asTuple

the first result should be (4,3), as the egg would be placed in the 4th box at position 3, the second result should be (3,1)
```

I think, this is not a too exotic problem, i am just too novice to tell what approach would be best practice.

Comment: Your description is confusing me. Do you want to: (a) wrap an array of `myStruct`s in an outer struct, and (b) having them share access to the same `grid` variable?

Comment: Yes, that is my intention.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `grid` as part of the initializer. This is a very common pattern:

```
init(_ value: (Int,Int,Int), in grid: Grid)
init(singleInt: Int, in grid: Grid)
```

There is no rule that says that the things you pass to `init` must be properties of the target.

---

In your "eggs" example, I think the confusion is that there's no reason (at least in your example) for eggs to know where they are. The type that is interesting here is the collection (the box or grid). It should be smart about locations inside itself. Eggs should be dumb about locations. It seems the problem is that you're trying to make your box type be `Array`, but this isn't the right tool; it's not smart enough for this problem. Create a `Box` type (or `Grid` type). It may contain an `Array` as a backing storage, but that's not really important. It may be easier to hold these as `[Int: Egg]` (or even just as a `Set` of indexes if Eggs have no internal structure).

The key here is that things should generally not insert themselves into collections or manage themselves inside of collections. Things should be passed to collections to be inserted and managed.

Comment: I was thinking of that one, and I will give it a try. I still haven't figured out, how to ensure that every instance has to be "owned" by an instance of the wrapper struct.

Comment: What do you mean by "owned" here? Remember; these are values. No one can "own" the number 4. The number 4 may be the result of a calculation, but it's just a value. If you need these elements to have strong ideas of ownership, that suggests a reference type (class), not a value type (struct).

Comment: I know that the term 'owned' has a certain meaning in terms of programming languages, but I am not referring to that. What I mean is that any instance of myStruct should only exist as an element of an array, which is a property of the outer struct. When I would take one element of such an array and append it into the respective array of another instance of the outer struct, it should be recalculated to match the 'grid' value of its new home. No instance of myStruct is supposed to exist on its own outside an array-property of  an instance of outerStruct.

Comment: "any instance of myStruct." The fact that you're saying "instance" indicates that you mean a reference type. Value types don't have instances. They're just values. Substitute "the number 4" in any place that you use "struct" (this isn't a joke; "4" is in fact a struct in Swift). Values to not "exist as elements." If you can talk about "where" it exists, it isn't a value type. It's a reference type. (Again, think about 4.) If this kind of behavior is important to you, you need to use classes, not structs. Two structs with the same property values must be indistinguishable.

Comment: The point here is that a struct is 100% defined by the values of its properties. If any other thing defines it (such as its location in a hierarchy), then it is a reference type, not a value type, and should be implemented as a class. This is important because when you pass or return a struct, it is copied, so you can't talk about where a struct "is;" it will by its nature have many clones.

Comment: Ok, actually, to decide if a class or a struct is better suited for a given scenario is indeed something I need to get more into. But do not let the fact that I used the term "instance"  mislead you into thinking I had made this decision already. I was not aware that I should not use this term on structs. Oviously, what I want to express is: any object manifestation of type myStruct.

Comment: Simple question: If I have two `myStruct` that have the same values in `valueAsTuple` and `valueAsInt`, are they always interchangeable? If the answer is yes, then they're value types (and it doesn't matter what grid they're related to). If the answer is "it matters what grid they're part of" then they are reference types. I'm not sure what you mean by "any object manifestation of type myStruct," but I want you to substitute the phrase "any object manifestation of type Int." If that doesn't make sense, then myStruct isn't a value type.

Comment: Another good example to learn from is `CGPoint`. Every "instance" of the point (x: 0, y: 1) is exactly interchangeable with any other "instance" of (x: 0, y: 1). The fact that points often have to be applied to a coordinate system (like a view's bounds vs a view's frame) isn't relevant. The point (x: 0, y: 1) doesn't "belong" to any particular view. It's just two numbers. If your type is like that, use struct. If it's not, use class, or rethink your struct so it's like a point.

Comment: I have edited my original question to give a more detailed example of what I would like to accomplish.

Comment: A solution would be that my egg only stores its absolute position, which is crucial for it to "know". It then could be stored into an array inside a smart structure. The information in which box it is to be found would then be a method of this structure. What is holding me off from doing so in the first place is, that the calculation would have to be done every single time I need the exact storing information. As the app I am aiming for will possibly be timing-sensitive (eggs are actual MIDI-events, boxes are musical bars), my thought is it would be better to have the position always at hand.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to move the calculations between `valueAsTuple` and `value` to the parent structure. 
It looks like you're storing grid indices and the calculation is dependent on the grid size.

This would be similar to the existing Collection APIs in Swift, where the collection is doing the math for its indices with functions like:

```
collection.index(after: anIndex)
collection.distance(from: anIndex, to: anotherIndex)
```

---

Other possibilities are:

1. Include the `grid` variable as an instance variable in `MyStruct`.
2. Store a reference to the parent type in `MyStruct` (only works if the parent type is a class)
3. Store `grid` in the parent struct and pass it to every function call which needs it.